# Why do I need both public and private keys to loginto a remote server?

Tags: ssh

To enable passwordless ssh to a server on my local network, I created a public and private rsa key pair.

1. I copied the public key to the  server (using `scp`).  I appended the contents of the public key to the `authorized_keys` file on the server.
2. I ensured that the permissions on the `authorized_keys` file are `-rw-------` for the user `me`.
3. I edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and added myself:

   AllowUsers root me
4. Then I restarted the SSH service on the server.

With both the public key and the private key in my .ssh folder, I am able to log into the server without being prompted for a password.

However, I noticed that if I *only* keep the private key in my computer's .ssh folder (and remove the public key), I am still prompted for a password.

(This is also true if I  *only* keep the public key in my computer's .ssh folder, but I expected that).

Why is it that I must have both the *private and public keys together* in my computer's .ssh folder, to successfully log into the server without a password?  (I would have expected that the private key is all that is required, because it matches with the public key on the server).

Here is the output...

```
me@my_computer:~/.ssh $ ls -1

known_hosts
me.my_server.local.rsa

me@my_computer:~/.ssh $ ssh -vvv me@my_server.local

OpenSSH_7.3p1 Ubuntu-1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "my_server.local" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to my_server.local [192.168.1.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3p1 Ubuntu-1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to my_server.local:22 as 'me'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/me/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from my_server.local
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1510/3072
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:gQHqj9GgzK4QOvUj+yAqeh9FE+6ldybMn7DKy5NJ+VY
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/me/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from my_server.local
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/me/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.100
debug1: Host 'my_server.local' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1574/3072
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
me@my_server.local's password:
```

Comment: Keeping only the private the key, add the output of `ssh -vvv server`. Also: "I have copied the public key to the server (using scp)"? Did you add it to `authorized_keys` or did you just copy the public key to some file?

Comment: I added it to `authorized_keys`.  I've pasted the output of `ssh -vvv` with the public key removed from the .ssh folder on my computer.

Comment: What is your private key named, exactly? All the options SSH tried returned with  "No such file or directory"

Comment: My private key is named me.my_server.local.rsa.  (It is listed in the output of `ls -1` above). The corresponding public key is named me.my_server.local.rsa.pub.  I see the error; it seems to be looking for a key named "id_rsa".  When I generated the key, I did specify the key name: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/me.my_server.local.rsa`.

Comment: then you should connect using `ssh -i me.my_myserver.local.rsa user@servee`. SSH only automatically tries the `id_*` files.

Comment: One more point, and I don't know if it is relevant... I save these keys in a safe place.  Whenever I reinstall Ubuntu, I copy the saved keys back to my ~/.ssh folder.  Should I be using some kind of import command (like gpg --import <private key name>` ) instead of simply copying the private key to ~/.ssh enough?